# netstat showing too many connections (Established)

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx, tcpip, netstat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Too Many ESTABLISHED connection from a single IP address in Apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/388906/too-many-established-connection-from-a-single-ip-address-in-apache)

netstat -ntp |grep 80 
shows too many **ESTABLISHED** connection from single IP address. Around 300 of them and it is **not an attack** and user is using a 2G connection to access our website using our mobile application. This is the case with other 2G connections also. As a result of this Apache is running out of children.

Earlier it was showing too many **close_wait** and after enabling **tcp_tw_reuse and tcp_tw-recycle and tcp-fin_timeout to 30** there is not much close_wait but the number of ESTABLISHED connections increased.We are using Ubuntu 11.04 apache version 2.2.17 with prefork. our mobile app deals with images mostly

**keepalive On

keepalive timeout 10

max clients 1000

max-request-perchild 4000

timeout 300**

On broadband connections there is no such issue. Connections are closing properly, but with 2G connections Apache is running out of children due to too many ESTABLISHED connections.

**we also tried turning off the keepalive** and timeout to 30 but sill this exist.Can anybody tell me why thus much established connection occurs from slow connections.

Is using mod_reqtimeout an option or should we move to ngnix server